# Use columns from a previously referenced table in a query as parameter values for a UDF...? Doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server-2005, parameters, user-defined-functions

Why can't I do this?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mtFirstTable t LEFT OUTER JOIN
    myUDF(t.somesolumn, t.someothercolumn) u
        ON t.somecolumn = u.somecolumn AND 
           t.someothercolumn = u.someothercolumn
```

I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "t.somecolumn" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "t.someothercolumn" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mtFirstTable t CROSS APPLY
    myUDF(t.somesolumn, t.someothercolumn) u
WHERE
    t.somecolumn = u.somecolumn AND 
    t.someothercolumn = u.someothercolumn
```

I hope you realize that joining a table to a function like this may cause performance problems.  The performance may be acceptable though.

Comment: Yeah that will work. Here's a good article on cross apply, and also talks about this as it relates to udf's. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/18/sql-server-cross-apply.aspx Incidentally, the answer is that the table myFirstTable is out of scope for the parameters of the UDF.